# Display result of mysql in braces

Tags: mysql, braces

I am writing the following query:

```
select c.place,a.type,group_concat(b.name) from place c
inner join menutype a
on c.id=a.id
inner join menuname b
on a.menuid=b.menuid
group by a.type
```

Result I am getting now is :

```
Place      Type      group_concat(Name)
A          Left      New Document,Vouchers
A          Top       Reports,Accounting
```

And I want the result like:

```
A     Left(New Document,Vouchers),Top(Reports,Accounting)
```

Kindly suggest me the way.Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select place, group_concat(value) from 
(select c.place, concat(a.type, '(', group_concat(b.name),')') as value from place c
inner join menutype a
on c.id=a.id
inner join menuname b
on a.menuid=b.menuid
group by a.type) tmp
group by place
```

Comment: What is value in group_concat(value)

Comment: In the inner query i have used alias "Value" which is Left(New Document,Vouchers) and Top(Reports,Accounting)